# drawContours function on english letters

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am developing an application that uses the output of the function `drawContours()`

The input is a photo (.jpg or .png) of text in italic, and I need to create rectangles around the letters using this function.

Now, when I draw the rectangles, I see that the function calculated 2 of them for some of the letters (for example the letters O and A).

Is it possible to preprocess the image s.t. the function only calculates the bigger rectangle for each letter like O and A?

[image]

The code that I used is the code in this link:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html

Only without the ellipse() function.

Comment: use flag: RETR_EXTERNAL

Comment: Attach the sample code you used to get this output ?

Comment: @ZdaR https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html

Without the ellipse code

Comment: @Silencer in which function?

Comment: That's hell a lot of illformatted code :/

Comment: @ZdaR check out the link, It has better formatting
The functions that I use to calculate the rectangle are minAreaRect() and approxPolyDP()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have several options... all of them explained in the documentation of [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours). Specifically the **mode** parameter.

I suppose you are using `CV_RETR_TREE`, this one says

> ...reconstructs a full hierarchy of nested contours...

This means you can select based on the hierarchy the ones you want to use. You can refer to the documentation about the structure of the hierarchy (it is explained fully in hierarchy parameter of this function), this will tell you if one contour is inside another one.

The other way is if you put `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` this one will only return the external contours, eliminating the inner ones from the output.

Also, it is possible with `CV_RETR_CCOMP`, but I have not used this one yet, but basically it will have a 2 hierarchy level and and one of them is the external contours.

So, everything depends if you need or not the internal contours on a later stage or not. If not I will recommend to use the `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`, if you need them later, use the TREE one.

Comment: Thanks! will check it out. If it works i'll reply again and mark your answer with V

Comment: Okay, I used CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, and now it only returns the contour surrounding the whole image, but no contours for the letters.

Comment: weird, I thought it took the black as background and that it should work... maybe white is background... I do not remmeber, but you can try the other way, the one with tree and hierarchy

Comment: Okay, I've dug into it a little deeper, and found out that the frame surrounding the whole image is because the source image is white and the text is black.
If you binarize the image, and swap the black with the white and the other way around, with cv::subtract(cv::Scalar::all(255), threshold_output, threshold_output);
You will get the desired output - no frame contour, just outer letters contour.

Add this to your answer and I'll mark it green :)